# What is the best way to analyze differences in demographics data among groups of different sizes

Tags: categorical-data, dataset, demography

I have groups of individuals in a population. These groups have different sizes--for example, group 1 has 50 individuals and group 2 has 1000 individuals. I want to show the differences in the groups' demographics data. I have categorical demographics like gender and location. I've thought about doing simple percentages for each group, but I feel like there must be a better way to do this.

I worked on doing chi squared testing between group number and each demographic variable and found they correlated, though I worried the differences in group size may have swayed the results. Is there a better way to do this? I've looked at a bar graph of the demographics of each group, but this graph is huge and cumbersome, so I'm looking for a mathematical way to do this.

Comment: Hi @anni. Are your demographic data population level (e.g. when you say "group 1 has 50 individuals", that means there are 50 individuals with that attribute in the population, as opposed to 50 individuals with that attribute in the a and > 50 in the population).

Comment: @AlexJ The groups were determined on variables other than demographic data. I'm trying to see if the group numbers, which were determined from factors other than the demographic data, somehow correlate with the demographics data or if the demographics data is significantly different among groups.

Comment: I reckon a chi-squared will do it :)

Comment: @AlexJ Is there any need to normalize because the groups are different sizes?

Comment: actually i might have got myself confused... am i correct, that you have various groups of different sizes. each group has various demographics. and you want to see if the different groups have different/same demographics to each other? to the population?

Comment: @AlexJ Yes! There are about 6 groups, the smallest has about 100 individuals and the largest has about 2,00o individuals. And I want to, like you said, see if the different groups have different/same demographics. I did the chi square test and my p value was so low it was a bit unbelievable. I didn't think the demographics would correlate with group number so well.

Comment: Hmm. What's the ultimate purpose of doing this? If you have six groups, and a number of demographics, and you're comparing them to each other, that's _lot_ of tests you're doing. This increases the chance of false positives due to multiple comparisons.

Comment: Sorry - I am not sure if I have a good answer about a statistical technique for your problem, btw.

Comment: @AlexJ basically I have 4 demographics: gender, region, age (which is grouped and categorical--think 0-10, 11-20), and city/country. When you add up two genders,  all the regions, and the 5 age groups, the bar graph I made becomes hard to read, so I'm looking for a mathematical analysis. To get to the point I'm at now, I did a cluster analysis based on non-demographic factors, which gave me 6 groups. Now, I want to analyze those categorical demographics in a meaningful way. I would love to relate it back to group number if possible, but at this point analyzing the individual groups would work.